# Uncertainty quantification Frequentist vs Bayesian

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

Is it actually possible to **quantify** the uncertainty in a frequentist setting? (e.g. using Maximum Likelihood Estimator).

Say that we have a dataset $\mathcal{D} = \{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ and assume that $y_i$ are i.i.d given some parameter $\theta$.

if I have a regression problem it is common to assume the likelihood function $p(\mathcal{D}|\theta)$ being Gaussian. Then since observations are indipendent and identically distributed we have

$$p(\mathcal{D}|\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(y_i|x_i,\theta) $$

where each $p(y_i|x_i,\theta) \sim \mathcal{N}(y_i|\mu,\sigma^2)$

Using maximum likelihood estimator we find

\begin{align}
&\mu_{ML} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\\
& \sigma^2_{ML} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\mu_{ML})^2 
\end{align}

Based on this procedure, the uncertainty I get does not depend on $x$ but it is just a fixed quantity (i.e. the $\bf{spread}$ of the distribution remains fixed once computed).

Instead, using a Bayesian inference approach and putting a gaussian conjugate prior dist. on the parameters we end up having a predictive distribution that looks like this

$$p(y_{new}|x_{new}) = \mathcal{N}(y_{new}|\mu(x),\sigma^2(x))$$

which takes specifically into account the input.

So, is it true that a Bayesian approach is more suitable to $\bf{quantify}$ uncertainty?

Or we can do something similar even with a classical inference approach using MLE?

EDIT:
[image]

This is a plot of Bayesian linear regression. As you can see, according to the notation I've used above, the red line corresponds to $\mu(x)$ while the light red-shaded region is the uncertainty associated to each input (\sigma^2(x)), that clearly depends on it.

So my question is, while Bayesian inference clearly quantifies input-depending uncertainty, can we do a similar thing under a classical inference setting?

Thanks,

James

Comment: x_new represents a new point that is not in the original dataset and y_new is the associated target that is of course random

Comment: Don't you also have that version in frequentist approach: $y_{new}\mid x_{new}, \mathcal{D}\sim N(\mu_{ML}(\mathcal{D}),\sigma^2_{ML}(\mathcal{D}))$?

Comment: yes but if you write just $\sigma^2_{ML}(\mathcal{D})$ you're considering a general fixed uncertainty for any point, while if the variance is a function of the input then you may have different spreads of the distribution on different target values and you may be able to quantify uncertainty on each single point. This is what I've understood but I can be wrong..

Comment: I've added some other details in my question.

Comment: Both Baysian and frequentist take the observed data $\mathcal{D}$ as absolute -- there are no uncertainty in the data itself.

Comment: the plot are referred to a prediction task where I have a bunch of new $x$ and I try to predict the corresponding target after having seen $\mathcal{D}$

Comment: Independent of what modelation You intent make sure whether this are a priori or a posteriori probabilities. The modells differ. You have to select for the type of variation. The given pictures look like univariate. The field of modells matching Your intention so far is multivariate. I might be path dependent too. You might look for something like [DistributionFitTest](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionFitTest.html) from Mathematica. On other hand You search for [PredictorMeasurements](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PredictorMeasurements.html).